# Get ISBN from Google Books API

Tags: android, google-api

I have been trying all evening to get ISBN number from google Books API from book title. So far after trying several solution from SO and Google, I have come upto below code where I am getting error in the line "BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader........"

My head is now totally blocked, so any help will be very very much appreciated ...

(I have API Key, which I am not using here during testing)

**CODE:**

```
public void getGoogle(View v) {
    String result = "";
        String link = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:'farmer+boy'+inauthor:'laura+ingalls+wilder'&projection=full&langRestrict=en&maxResults=1";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL(link);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        try 
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"),8);
                String line = responseReader.readLine();
                while (line != null){
                    builder.append(line + "\n");
                    line = responseReader.readLine();
                }
                connection.disconnect();
            result = builder.toString();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result: " + e.toString());
        }

        // parse json data
        try 
        {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            String isbn;
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
            isbn = json.getString("kind");
            EditText isbnfld = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.isbn);
            isbnfld.setText(isbn);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error parsing data.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem importing data.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
12-04 11:32:06.025: E/log_tag(1761): Error converting result: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error pulling a large JSON response. I switched from BufferedReader to use BasicResponseHandler instead. Try this:

```
    HttpClient client = new  DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:'farmer+boy'+inauthor:'laura+ingalls+wilder'&projection=full&langRestrict=en&maxResults=1");
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = null;
    try{
        responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;


    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        System.out.println("JSONRESPONSE ="+jsonObject);

    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.v("TEST","Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is this JSONParser class? Is it some user defined class? I am getting error on that.

Comment: Whoops. Corrected it for JSONObject. JSON Parser is a class my code was using for some stuff. JSONObject should do what you need it to do

Comment: Error was caused by running the code inside main UI .. after I moved to AsyncTask, it was okay.. thanks.